# Express not loading in URL

Tags: node.js, express

I currently have an express server I'm running based on the express tutorial.

Here is my code for server.js

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 3000

app.get('/', (req, res) => res.send('Hello World!'))

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}!`))
```

the server.js file is in a directory on my server:

```
http://myurl.com/node-webshot/server.js
```

I start the server with: npm start
and get this:

```
> webshot@0.18.0 start /home/myurl/node-webshot
> node server.js

Example app listening on port 3000!
```

when I go to my url: http://myserver.com/node-webshot/
I see the directory listing only:
[image]

note "myserver.com" is just a fill in to path  for working folder.

My expected result would be that when I go to the roof of the file where server.js is loaded that it would show the "Hello world".  Not sure what I'm missing here.

Comment: simply go to http://<serverName>:port/

Comment: Cannot GET /preview/productpreview/node-webshot @xan_z

Comment: I see your comment works, not url where I was pointing to.  Since I placed server.js file in specific folder I was calling that route.  @xan_z

Comment: you don't call your server side files/code - they are served by the server based on the routes you have. - and hence you invoke the routes based on the server IP/DNS and port - followed by the route - as you have only one get route of '/' - that is the only thing which can be done with the above code for now.

Comment: Is there anyway to expose the url path with out using a port?  For example I'd like to just go to the url like this "http://myurl.com/node-webshot/" @xan_z

Comment: 1 - default port - this is assumed even if not specified - 80 for http and 443 for https - so if you expose your app on port 80 on http - you don't have to specify the port 2- having a DNS server setup which can then map that DNS - to your server - ideally you have a DNS server - which resolves to VIP which will route the request to one of the pool member servers on which your app is hosted - this is a typical production setup.